# How to return a sqlalchemy query as a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, sqlalchemy

I am working with the [panoply SDK](https://github.com/panoplyio/panoply-python-sdk) in python. [Panoply website documentation](https://panoply.io/docs/data-sources/python-sdk/)

Panoply is a data warehouse and I am using the SDK in python to write directly into the warehouse. I am using `sqlalchemy` to query my results from a mysql database and the SDK requires the result to be in a dictionary.

```
{ "column": "value" }
```

my code so far:

```
>>>from sqlalchemy import create_engine

>>>result = engine.execute("""\
SELECT 
    creation_date, 
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY 1 
""")

>>>result = result.fetchall()
>>>result
[('2020-02-05', 41606), ('2020-02-06', 31223)]
>>>cols = result.keys()
>>>cols
['creation_date', 'trips']
```

Panoply Example:

```
import panoply
conn = panoply.SDK( "APIKEY", "APISECRET" )
conn.write( "tablename", { "foo": "bar" } )
```

How do I get my `sqlalchemy` query into the format panoply needs to write into the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since panoply supports writing only one row at a time, there's no need to use the `fetchall` method to retrieve all the rows into memory at once, which can be very memory inefficient. Instead, iterate through the cursor and use the `items` method to retrieve each row as a sequence of key-value tuples so that you can construct a dict with the `dict` constructor to feed into panoply's `write` method:

```
for row in result:
    conn.write('tablename', dict(row.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help...

```
>>> rows = result.fetchall()
>>> results = [dict(row) for row in rows]
```

Comment: That would make every row a separate dictionary though

Comment: That gave me what i thought i needed but when i attempt to write into the database I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`